# Error in Redirect from Apache to Tomcat using mod_proxy

Tags: apache, tomcat, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I have apache and Tomcat in my server and im using mod_proxy to redirect from Apache to Tomcat... the apache is running on port 80 and tomcat is running on port 8080
here is my virtual host :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.example.ir
   ServerAlias example.ir
   ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyPreserveHost On

   <Proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
   </Proxy>

   ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/example
   ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/example

   <Location "/">
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
   </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

But the problem is when I try www.example.com i get the following error :

> HTTP Status 404 - /exampleexample/

so whats wrong with my configuration ?
Thanks and sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to execute Tomcat's examples webapp? If this is the case, try following configuration:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/examples/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/examples/
```

After restarting your Apache, navigate to `http://yourhost/`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks man! its work but now i have another problem.my example app not loading properly.its title loads but then its stop loading and nothing happens.Thanks again for your answer!